# Function composition does not work unless used with dot operator

Tags: haskell

Why does the first case works OK but not the second? I believe . operator chains the function and since f returns Boolean i could "not" it, but why does it not work in the second case?

```
*Main> let filterNot f xs = filter (not . f) xs
*Main> let filterNot f xs = filter (not (f)) xs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because there is a difference between `not . f` and `not f`.  If you want to do it without using `.`, you'll have to use a lambda:

```
filterNot f xs = filter (\x -> not (f x)) xs
```

But this is precisely the definition of `.`!

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

---

Just because `f` returns a `Bool` does not mean that you can `not` it.  You can only `not` a `Bool` itself, not a function that returns one.  There is a large difference between `a -> Bool` and just `Bool`.  The definition of `not` is

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
not True = False
not False = True
```

So if `f` itself is not `True` or `False` exactly, then you can't apply `not` to it.

(Whew, that's a not of negatives in this explanation)

Comment: I suppose there are people you'd like `class Booly

Comment: Sorry another question related to this, why the following do not work "let dd xs = map (*2) . filter odd xs" but when i remove the xs from both side it does

Comment: @RohitSharma you could do `let dd xs = (map (*2) . filter odd) xs`, which is what lets you drop the argument.